# What do we call the line of a character in a video game when he makes an attack?

Tags: terminology

Here's the line is referred to as a sound effect, but it's too vague in my opinion, because it's something that's voiced by a character and not just a sound. Is there a more specific word in the context of video games?

Answer (score 1):

He's just calling out his attacks. [TVTropes has a great article](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CallingYourAttacks) on this.

Conversely, if the character was a spellcaster of sorts, it would be an incantation. If the character was a superhero, it would be an invocation.